# Search & Highlight Multi Keywords

Tags: php

When I press 'process' button I want the text highlights the related words on keywords something like this:

[image]

I try using preg_replace($keyword, $keywords) not work. Any body help? Thank  you !

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
<?php
$str="Hello World You are on StackOverflow";// Your large text
$arrMatchWords=array("World","on");// Provide all your matching text.

foreach($arrMatchWords as $k=>$v)
{
    $str=str_replace($v,"<span style='background:#ffff00'>".$v."</span>",$str);
}

echo ($str);
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
$keywords = array("computers" => NULL,"paper" => NULL, "rocket" => NULL);
$text = preg_split('/\s/', $my_text_string);
foreach($text as $key => $value)
{
  if(array_key_exists($value, $keywords)) {
          echo $value . "\n";
            $text[$key] = '<span style="background:yellow">'. $value . '</span>';
    }
}

$my_text_string = implode(' ', $text);
echo $my_text_string;
?>
```